# GNU Make only executes 10 rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that shall convert some files into PDFs. Right now the makefile looks like this:

```
PDFS = file_A.pdf file_B.pdf <snip> file_K.pdf

all : convert

file_%.pdf:
    $(CONVERTER_COMMAND) $< -o $@

file_A.pdf : file1.ext
file_B.pdf : file2.ext
<snip>
file_K.pdf : file11.ext

convert : $(PDFS)
.PHONY : convert
```

The above is the general structure (unfortunately I can't show the actual file).

Running `make convert` works like a charm for the first 10 files, i.e. it generates `file_A.pdf` up until `file_J.pdf`. The last one however, `file_K.pdf`, is never generated. If I move the rule for it to the top of the list it gets generated, but then the now last one in the list no longer gets generated.

If I do `make file_K.pdf` make just state the file is `up to date`, even though it does not yet exist.

Any ideas? Or any alternative ideas on how to solve similar problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a stray TAB character on the line after the last prerequisite statement (after `file_K.pdf : file11.ext` in the list above)?

You should try running `make -d` and see what it has to say about the targets that it doesn't build.

Comment: Gah, you were right. There was a stray TAB right there. Thanks a lot, mate!